# Explicit instantiation of user defined conversion operator

Tags: c++, visual-c++

What is the correct syntax for explicit instantiation of conversion operators?

I have the following header `a.h`

```
class A
{
public:
  template<typename T> operator T();
};
```

and the implementation `a.cxx`

```
#include "a.h"
template<typename T> A::operator T() {return 1;}
template A::operator int();
```

GCC 6.3 compiles as expected, but VC 14 (Visual Studio 2015) says:

> error C2549: user-defined conversion cannot specify a return type

Is this an error in my code or a bug in VC? What would be the correct syntax vor VC?

Comment: Setting aside the compilation error you'are asking about, which looks like a bug in VC, this code [is ultimately doomed to fail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file).

Comment: With GCC, the following main.cxx works as expected:<code>#include "a.h"
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
  A a;
  auto b = static_cast<int>(a);
  std::cout << b << std::endl;
  return 0;
}</code>. Without explicit instantiation it gives a link time error.

Comment: Now try it without explicit instantiation. The whole point of having templates is to have the compiler itself write the code for you. Being forced to explicitly instantiate ***every*** template instance defeats the purpose of having a template, somewhat.

Comment: This depends on the particular situation. In my case, as the author of A, I know for which Ts the conversions from A to T make sense. I could, of course, avoid templates, list all these Ts explicitely in the header and repeat the implementation in a.cxx. This, however, would be cumbersome and harder to maintain.